# How can i access 'invocation' variable from Return Values in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

When running debug mode with Ansible Playbook i can clearly see that one of returned values is "invocation" however i struggle trying to get it form playbook. "register: xyz" Allows you only to get "msg, status failed, changed" form returned values (at least in task i use - proxmox_kvm). Is there a way of accessing rest of them?

My code:

```
---
  - hosts: pve
    become: yes
    vars:
     passwd: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          <encrypted-password>
    tasks:
     - name: Stop VM
       proxmox_kvm:
        api_user    : root@pam
        api_password: "{{ passwd }}"
        api_host    : 10.0.0.1
        name        : "{{ vm_name }}"
        node        : my-node
        state       : current
       register: output

     - debug:
        var: output
```

Output value from 'register':

```
 "output": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "VM RHEL8.1 with vmid = 101 is stopped",
        "status": "stopped"
```

List of returned vars:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html